# requests.exceptions.SSLError With Flask GitHub Oauth

Tags: python, flask, oauth

I am attempting to use [Flask-Github](https://github-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to authorize users for my app. However, when `github.authorize` is called from my `/login` route, the error

> > > requests.exceptions.SSLError
> > >       SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/oauth/access_token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)'),))

is raised. My current app setup is below:

```
import flask
from flask_github import GitHub
github = GitHub(app)
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'] = '***************'
app.config['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'] = '*************************'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
  if flask.session.get('username'):
    return flask.redirect('/user/{}'.format(user.username))
  return github.authorize(scope="user:email")

@github.access_token_getter
def token_getter():
   if flask.session['git_token']:
      return current_user

@app.route('/callback')
@github.authorized_handler
def authorized(oauth_token):
  if oauth_token is None:
     return flask.redirect("/")
  user_github_data = github.get('user')
  return flask.redirect('/{}'.format(user_github_data['name']))
```

On GitHub Oauth Application settings, my home url is set to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and my callback route to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback`. Does anyone know how this error can be resolved? I am using Mac OSX, Python 2.7, `requests 2.18.4`,`pyopenssl` for Python 2.7.

Comment: What environment do you have? OS, Python version, OpenSSL version, requests version?

Comment: @KlausD. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: I think this is because of **deprecation of TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 support by GitHub** in February 2018. See https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: @Anupam Ah, I did not know about. That explains the error. Thank you.